# How do I change the shortcut icon back? v2.81

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

I was looking up some shortcuts and pressed some combination of key that change one of the icons. See the highlighted icon in the image. That icon is from the icon sidebar on the left edge of the screen. This one used to be the "box select" icon and now it's the "Tweak" icon. I would like to change it back.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have likely pressed the <kbd>W</kbd> key. Press it again several times to cycle through the different selector options

Answer (score 2):

Ok after some more playing I found it. Any of the icons with the arrow in the corner you can left click and hold to bring up a sub menu.

Also using the keyboard shortcut for box select will change the icon to that again.

Comment: Yes and here are a few things that may help, https://youtu.be/w-5Z1vuEinE